# How to debug in ko template in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, template, knockoutjs

Here is the code in \vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping-address\custom-method-item-template.html

```
<tbody collapsible="as: '$collapsible_' + method.method_code">
<tr class="row"
    click="element.selectShippingMethod">
    <td class="col col-method">
        <input type="radio"
               class="radio"
               ifnot="method.error_message"
               ko-checked="element.isSelected"
               ko-value="method.carrier_code + '_' + method.method_code"
               attr="'aria-labelledby': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code + ' ' + 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code,
                    'checked': element.rates().length == 1 || element.isSelected" />
    </td>
    <td class="col col-price">
        <each args="element.getRegion('price')" render="" />
    </td>
    <td class="col col-method"
        attr="'id': 'label_method_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.method_title" style="background-color:yellow" />
    <td class="col col-carrier"
        attr="'id': 'label_carrier_' + method.method_code + '_' + method.carrier_code"
        text="method.carrier_title" />
    <!-- Column with collapsible trigger  -->
    <td class="col">
        <a toggleCollapsible="'$collapsible_' + method.method_code">
            <span data-bind="i18n: 'Info'"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
<!-- Row for shipping method description -->
<tr class="row" visible="$context['$collapsible_' + method.method_code].opened">
    <td class="col" colspan="5" i18n="'Some description.'">12312</td>
</tr>

<tr class="row row-error"
    if="method.error_message">
    <td class="col col-error" colspan="4">
        <div role="alert" class="message error">
            <div text="method.error_message"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="no-display">
            <input type="radio"
                   attr="'value' : method.method_code, 'id': 's_method_' + method.method_code" />
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

I want to show method.method_code either console.log or alert, how can i do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Debugging

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.computed(function() { debugger; })"></div>
```

Print Data

```
<div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(method.method_code)"></div>
```

**Docs from Magento:**
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/troubleshoot/ui_comp_troubleshoot_js.html

Comment: also you can follow  documentation https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/troubleshoot/ui_comp_troubleshoot_js.html

Answer (score 1):

> Knockoutjs context debugger

Do not work anymore with Chrome ver 92 you can simply select the element and inspect it and after that run in the console drawer :

```
require('ko').contextFor($0);
```

And it will output the KO context

Answer (score 1):

[Context Knockout Hover](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/knockout-context-hover/lcpnkclcbpmhekkjnkomhoecoiobbejf) is the way to go after they removed the other Knockout extension from Chrome marketplace.

Sample:
[image]